# Custom brush size scales back when changing brush

Tags: adobe-photoshop

So I downloaded some free custom brushes to draw some hills.
The "default" size of these brushes are ~850px so I change it to 35px. But if I use another brush and then switch back to this, then it always scales back to 850px.

So, if I change a brush size then how to achieve to "stay" at this size forever?
(sorry for my English, if something is bad)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you have the 35px size brush:

1. Go to the brush list.
2. Click the arrow at the upper right corner and choose `New brush preset`. [image]

That will save the brush in its current size and other brush options and places it at the bottom of the brush list.

---

---

You can also do about the same thing with brush tool presets ( Saves opacity and size etc...  ).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the pictures. I wanted to vote up too, but 15 rep points needed:(

Comment: @CriticalPoint: If that size is something that you use really often, it might help you to make and action to change the brush size. Here's a tutorial on how to make actions: http://psd.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-tips/introduction-to-actions-photoshop/ - Basically: **1.** Make a new action. Assign it a hotkey and start recording it. **3.** Go to change your brush size. **4.** Stop recording the action. Then you could select a brush from your brush list and press hotkey to change the size quickly. I can add this to my answer in more detail if you're interested.

Comment: Very good idea, don't need to edit your answer, I can do this.